# Removing leading and trailing all-nan axis for multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to remove all leading and trailing all-NaN axis (rows & columns & whatever they are called with arrays with more than 3 dimensions). While it's quite straight-forward with known dimensions I can't think of a good way to do this with arbitary dimensional arrays.

For example

```
import numpy as np
arr1d = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan])
# expected result: np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])

arr2d = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                  [1., 2., np.nan], 
                  [4., np.nan, np.nan]])
# expected result: np.array([[1., 2.], [4., np.nan]])

arr3d = np.array([[[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [1., np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
                  [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [2., np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
                  [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [3., np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]])
# expected result: np.array([[[1.]], [[2.]], [[3.]]])
```

For the 1D case it's pretty easy:

```
notnans = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(arr1d))
if notnans.size:
    trimmed = arr1d[notnans[0]: notnans[-1]+1]  # slice from first not-nan to the last one
else:
    trimmed = np.zeros(0)
```

But I'm struggling with the approach for multidimensional arrays (preferably vectorized).

Comment: I think your last output is wrong - it should be `np.array([[[1.]], [[2.]], [[3.]]]`

Comment: @Eric Thanks for spotting that, it's corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrasing this problem as *"find the indices to crop leading and trailing `False`s from a predicate array of `bool`"*, you can do this by iterating over axes, and using the multiple-axis form of `any`:

```
def arg_trim_zeros(pred, axis=None):
    """
    Produces an nd slice index that trims zeros from the specified dimensions
    """
    # allow multiple axis arguments like other numpy functions
    all_axes = tuple(range(pred.ndim))
    if axis is None:
        axis = all_axes
    elif not isinstance(axis, tuple):
        axis = (axis,)

    slices = [slice(None)] * pred.ndim

    # special case if entire input is falsey
    if not pred.any():
        for ax in axis:
            slices[ax] = slice(0, 0)
        return slices

    # compute slices for each dimension in turn
    for ax in axis:
        valid = pred.any(axis=all_axes[:ax] + all_axes[ax+1:])

        # argmax is safe here, because we're sure there is at least one True in pred
        start = valid.argmax()
        stop = len(valid) - valid[::-1].argmax()
        slices[ax] = slice(start, stop)

    return tuple(slices)
```

So in your case, this is:

```
cropped = arr[arg_trim_zeros(~np.isnan(arr))]
```

Which has the bonus of returning a copy of the original array.

The axis argument isn't strictly needed here, but I thought I'd add it to solve the more general problem.

Comment: I like the reformulation of the problem! That really has more uses than just to strip all-nans. It's a shame that numpy just has a really slow [`trim_zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html) function instead of more general utilities like this.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this should make it into numpy as an ND replacement then?

Comment: It also feels like this could be made more efficient by storing intermediate results - eg, `x = pred.any(axis=(1, 2)), y = pred.any(axis=(1, 3))` could be sped up by calculating `z = np.any(pred, axis=1, keepdims=True); x = z.any(axis=2), y = z.any(axis=3)`

Comment: So, `arr3d[arg_trim_zeros(arr3d)]` is supposed to return `np.array([[[1.], [2.], [3.]]])`, right? Or am I using it wrongly?

Comment: @Divakar: You need to pass a predicate, `~np.isnan(arr)`, not the original array

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach using [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
def remove_nans(a):
    acc = np.maximum.accumulate
    m = ~np.isnan(a)
    n = a.ndim

    if n==1:
        return a[acc(m) & acc(m[::-1])[::-1]]    
    else:
        r = np.tile(np.arange(n),n)
        per_axis_combs = np.delete(r,range(0,len(r),n+1)).reshape(-1,n-1)
        per_axis_combs_tuple = map(tuple,per_axis_combs)

        mask = []
        for i in per_axis_combs_tuple:            
            m0 = m.any(i)            
            mask.append(acc(m0) & acc(m0[::-1])[::-1])
        return a[np.ix_(*mask)]
```

Sample runs -

1) 1D Case :

```
In [246]: arr1d
Out[246]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,   4.,  nan])

In [247]: remove_nans(arr1d)
Out[247]: array([  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,   4.])
```

2) 2D Case :

```
In [248]: arr2d_2
Out[248]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [249]: remove_nans(arr2d_2)
Out[249]: 
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan]])
```

3) 3D Case :

```
In [250]: arr3d_2
Out[250]: 
array([[[ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [  1.,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [  4.,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [  2.,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [  3.,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan]]])

In [251]: remove_nans(arr3d_2)
Out[251]: 
array([[[  1.],
        [ nan],
        [  4.]],

       [[  2.],
        [ nan],
        [ nan]],

       [[  3.],
        [ nan],
        [ nan]]])
```

Comment: Worth noting that this approach returns a copy, whereas mine returns a view

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of your 1d that removes nans relative to the last axis.

```
def remove_nans(arr):
    i = tuple(range(arr.ndim-1))
    idx=np.isnan(arr).all(axis=i)
    notnans = np.nonzero(~idx)[0]
    return arr[...,notnans]

In [135]: remove_nans(arr1d)
Out[135]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
In [136]: remove_nans(arr2d)
Out[136]: 
array([[ nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.],
       [  4.,  nan]])
In [137]: remove_nans(arr3d)
Out[137]: 
array([[[ nan],
        [  1.],
        [ nan]],

       [[ nan],
        [  2.],
        [ nan]],

       [[ nan],
        [  3.],
        [ nan]]])
```

In the 2d case, I can apply it again on the transpose

```
In [138]: remove_nans(remove_nans(arr2d).T).T
Out[138]: 
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  4.,  nan]])
```

Which means we should be able to do the same, recursively with the 3d.  But getting the transpose right is trickier.

```
In [139]: temp = remove_nans(arr3d)
In [140]: temp = remove_nans(temp.transpose(0,2,1)).transpose(0,2,1)
In [141]: temp
Out[141]: 
array([[[ 1.]],

       [[ 2.]],

       [[ 3.]]])
In [142]: temp = remove_nans(temp.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0)
In [143]: temp
Out[143]: 
array([[[ 1.],
        [ 2.],
        [ 3.]]])
```

So the generalized multidimensional case would just have to iterate through all dimensions, and swap each with the last and apply the remove.

```
def all_remove(arr):
    temp = remove_nans(arr)
    for i in range(arr.ndim-1):
        temp = remove_nans(temp.swapaxes(i,-1)).swapaxes(i,-1)
    return temp
In [169]: all_remove(arr1d)
Out[169]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
In [170]: all_remove(arr2d)
Out[170]: 
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  4.,  nan]])
In [171]: all_remove(arr3d)    # not the same as before
Out[171]: 
array([[[ 1.]],

       [[ 2.]],

       [[ 3.]]])
```

I tried  `temp = np.moveaxis(remove_nans(np.moveaxis(temp, i,-1)),-1,i)` and got the same result.  I'd have to examine other 3d and 4d cases to track down the difference.

Though one might argue that these last cases are right:

```
In [196]: arr3d[:,:,[0]][:,[1],:][:,:,:]
Out[196]: 
array([[[ 1.]],

       [[ 2.]],

       [[ 3.]]])
```

Comment: The last case was a question typo